# Group search result from multiple indices to single hits in Algolia

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I am trying to implement the Algolia search. I am using PHP.

Scenario:
I have three tables (products, resources, and news). I am currently using MultipleQueries (DOCs Link Here) from this documentation.

As a result, I am getting results in the following format as in the documentation.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "hits": [
        {
            ........
        },
        ],
        "page": 0,
        "nbHits": 1,
        "nbPages": 1,
        "hitsPerPage": 20,
        "processingTimeMS": 1,
        "query": "jimmie paint",
        "params": "query=jimmie+paint&attributesToRetrieve=firstname,lastname&hitsPerPage=50"
        "index": "people"
    },
    {
      "hits": [
        {
            ...........
        },
        {
            ...........
        }
        ],
        "page": 0,
        "nbHits": 1,
        "nbPages": 1,
        "hitsPerPage": 20,
        "processingTimeMS": 1,
        "query": "jimmie paint",
        "params": "query=jimmie+paint&attributesToRetrieve=firstname,lastname&hitsPerPage=50"
        "index": "famous_people"
    },
    {
        ..............
    }
  ]
}
```

This is great, but WHAT I WANT is to group the results of 3 indices into single hits. Below is a sample I am expecting from the API.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "hits": [
        {
            ........
        },
        {
            ........
        },
        {
            ........
        },
        {
            ........
        },
        {
            ........
        },
        {
            ........
        },
        {
            ........
        },

        ],
        "page": 0,
        "nbHits": 1,
        "nbPages": 1,
        "hitsPerPage": 20,
        "processingTimeMS": 1,
        "query": "jimmie paint",
        "params": "query=jimmie+paint&attributesToRetrieve=firstname,lastname&hitsPerPage=50"
        "index": "indices goes here"
    },
  ]
}
```

I searched a lot but could not come with suitable solution. Is this even possible using Algolia. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of aggregation across multiple indices baked into Algolia. You'll have to aggregate the hit records yourself via code before displaying.

It's more typical for Algolia users to display results from multiple indices in a federated way using one of the front end libraries. Autocomplete is great at this:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/solutions/ecommerce/search/autocomplete/federated-search/#combining-different-data-sources